# How do I pass a table to a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am making my first attempt at creating a stored procedure (using VS2012 to edit) I am trying to pass my stored procedure a table with two columns. However when I click on parse to check my code I get the following errors.

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SaveMsgData, Line 10
>   Incorrect syntax near 'READONLY'.
>
> Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Procedure SaveMsgData, Line 45
>   Must declare the table variable "@tagList".

I think the last two errors stem from the first, but I have no idea what is causing the first. As far as I can tell my syntax is correct.

Here is my full code.

```
CREATE TYPE TagListType AS TABLE
(                     
       TagID varchar(100),                
       AntNum int
);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE SaveMsgData 
    @Mac nvarchar(30),
    @tagList TagListType READONLY
AS
    DECLARE @ReaderID int
    DECLARE @AntList TABLE (AntennaID int, AntNum int)

    SELECT @ReaderID = -1

    SELECT @ReaderID = Id
    FROM dbo.Readers
    WHERE MAC = @Mac

    IF (@ReaderID >= 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @AntList (AntennaID,Antnum,TargetNumOfTags) 
            SELECT id, AntennaNumber, numOfTags 
            FROM Antennae
            WHERE ID = @ReaderID

        DECLARE @count int
        DECLARE @len int                    

        SET @count = 0
        SET @len = 0

        WHILE @count <= @len
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @LocalAnt int
            DECLARE @LocalTarget int
            DECLARE @LocalAntID int
            DECLARE @LocalStatus int
            DECLARE @LocalTagsRead int

            SELECT @LocalAnt = Antnum, @LocalTarget = TargetNumOfTags, @LocalAntID = AntID 
            FROM #AntList 
            WHERE Antnum = @count

            SELECT @LocalTagsRead = COUNT(*) FROM @tagList WHERE AntNum = @count

            IF @LocalTagsRead = @LocalTarget
            BEGIN
                SET @LocalStatus = 0
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @LocalStatus = 1
            END

        INSERT INTO Readings 
        VALUES (@LocalStatus, @LocalTarget, @LocalTagsRead, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @LocalAntID, @ReaderID)

        --Will insert Tags in to tag table here later.
        SET @count = @count + 1
    END
END
GO
```

The intent here is to have have my C# desktop application use this stored procedure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Table-valued parameters are available as of SQL Server **2008** - judging from the error message, you're most likely *not* running against a 2008 instance....

Are you truly on a 2008 or newer server engine??

Find out by using `SELECT @@VERSION` against your server - what does it report back?

Comment: ..... *Face Palm* I  am still on 2005, our IT manager is planning on upgrading to 2012 soon. For some reason I was thinking he had already moved my DB over.

Comment: Just an update. I got SQL Server 2012 Express installed on my semi rogue virtual machine and parsed my code with that, it parsed just fine. So I am back on track with my project and the IT manager can migrate my main DB over when he gets to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a CSV parameter and convert it into XML with this function:

```
create function udf_CsvToXML(@Csv as varchar(4096),@Delim as varchar(15)=',')
returns xml
as
begin
    declare @xml as xml = CAST('<XML>'+('<X>'+REPLACE(@Csv,@Delim,'</X><X>')+'</X></XML>') AS XML)
    return @xml
end
```

Then, you can use the XML in a join or whatever else as if it was a table:

```
DECLARE @TitlesXML as XML = dbo.udf_CsvToXML(@Titles,',')
select distinct t
from p
join    (SELECT N.value('.[1]', 'varchar(25)') as value FROM @TitlesXML.nodes('/XML/X') as T(N)) tt
    on tt.value = p.t
```